# Making element referencing less clunky

Tags: javascript, html

I am new to javascript so please forgive me if this is a simple answer. I cannot seem to find it. I have a small block of script that replaces text based on the content of the paragraph. Very easy. My questions is, why do I have to right out the entire reference twice? Does the variable not point to the same thing? Is there a simpler way?

This works:

```
<p id="name">Electric City</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var name = document.getElementById("name").innerHTML;
    if (name == "Electric City") {
        document.getElementById("name").innerHTML = "Welcome!";
    }
</script>
```

This doesn't:

```
<p id="name">Electric City</p>

<script type="text/javascript">
    var name = document.getElementById("name").innerHTML;
    if (name == "Electric City") {
        name = "Welcome!";
    }
</script>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var name = document.getElementById("name").innerHTML;
```

That line of code gets the *value* from your "name" element (using its `innerHTML` property) and copies it to the variable `name`. The `name` variable does not refer to the "name" element itself.

If you want to simplify your code, you could do something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var nameElement = document.getElementById("name");
    if (nameElement.innerHTML  == "Electric City") {
        nameElement.innerHTML = "Welcome!";
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

In JavaScript, saying `variable = value` doesn't affect the thing that `variable` originally referred to.  Saying `variable.property = value` *does* affect the thing that `variable` refers to.

So to simplify the code, do this:

```
var element = document.getElementById("name");
if (element.innerHTML == "Electric City") {
    element.innerHTML = "Welcome!";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/MPya7/)

Try this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var name = document.getElementById("name");
    if (name.innerHTML == "Electric City") {
        name.innerHTML = "Welcome!";
    }
</script>
```

`name` is only holding the value and isn't referencing the actual element as a whole.

You need to grab the element THEN check and apply the `innerHTML` to it.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
var elem = document.getElementById("name");
if (elem.innerHTML == "Electric City") {
    elem.innerHTML = "Welcome!";
}
```

The problem is that you had a reference to a string, not a reference to the object that holds the string. Since strings are immutable, setting a new value of a string variable just creates a whole new string and leaves the original (that was referred to my your element) untouched.

Answer (score 0):

as simple as this

```
   <p id="demo">Electric City</p>

    <script>

    var str = document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML; 
    var res = str.replace(/Electric City/gi," Welcome!");
    document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML=res;
    </script>
```

or

```
<script>
    var str = document.getElementById("demo"); 
    var res = str.innerHTML.replace(/Electric City/gi," Welcome!");
    str.innerHTML=res;
</script>
```